# cmath header confusion

Tags: c++

What is the namespace for math functions? Global or `std`?

Consider [cos](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cmath/cos/) function. It has 3 overloads. But there is also legacy `cos` from math.h. C doesn't know anything about function overloading. Therefore `cos(x)` can't be resolved to `cos(float)`. The solution is to call the single precision version explicitly `cosf(x)`. Did I miss anything?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You get the same functions by including `<math.c>` and `<cmath>` in C++, the only differences is the namespace. I.E. including `<math.h>` also gives you the overload.

In theory, in C++03, using `<math.h>` gives you the symbols defined in the global namespace and also in the std namespace while using `<cmath>` gives you the symbols defined in the std namespace and not in the global namespace.

The practice is different and C++ 0X aligned the theory with the practice. `<math.h>` gives you the symbols defined in the global namespace and perhaps also in the std namespace while using `<cmath>` gives you the symbols defined in the std namespace and perhaps also in the global namespace.

Comment: Actually, the 03 standard doesn't explicitly disallow cmath putting stuff in the global namespace as well, and this is borne out by the fact that then new 0x standard explicitly allows it.

Comment: @paxdiablo, well looking at http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-defects.html#206 it seems that I was indeed wrong about C++03.  But in the opposite direction, it was even more strict than I though. I'm updating my answer.

Comment: It is my recollection that the *intent* in C++03 was, the `<cfoo>` headers should not put things in the global namespace; however, that proved to be very difficult to implement even in contexts where you'd think everyone was cooperating (like gcc with glibc) and also more trouble for people using the headers than it was really worth.  I like that C++0x has backed off on that a bit.

Comment: @AProg, I'm confused. Point 206 of that link has to do with the possible discrepancies between the different `new` operators. How does it relate to namespace population by the two types of headers? And I think the second para is still not quite correct - there is nothing in C++03 stating that cmath is not _allowed_ to place things in global namespace. It just states that it populates std and leaves it at that.

Answer (score 3):

They are in the `std` namespace.  But, for backwards compatibility reasons the `cmath` header also shows them in the global namespace with a `using std::cos;`.

Answer (score 1):

The `cXXX` headers place all their stuff in the `std` namespace. They *may* also put them in the global namespace but it's not required.

This is from C++0x, the upcoming standard, section D.7:

> 2/ Every C header, each of which has a name of the form `name.h`, behaves as if each name placed in the standard library namespace by the corresponding `cname` header is placed within the global namespace scope. It is unspecified whether these names are first declared or defined within namespace scope (3.3.6) of the namespace `std` and are then injected into the global namespace scope by explicit using-declarations (7.3.3).
>
> 3/ [ Example: The header `<cstdlib>` assuredly provides its declarations and definitions within the namespace `std`. It may also provide these names within the global namespace. The header `<stdlib.h>` assuredly provides the same declarations and definitions within the global namespace, much as in the C Standard. It may also provide these names within the namespace `std`. —end example ]

This is unchanged from section D.5 from C++03 (it's made more explicit in the newer standard but the effect is the same):

> 2/ Every C header, each of which has a name of the form `name.h`, behaves as if each name placed in the Standard library namespace by the corresponding `cname` header is also placed within the namespace scope of the namespace `std` and is followed by an explicit using-declaration.
>
> 3/ [Example: The header `<cstdlib>` provides its declarations and definitions within the namespace `std`. The header `<stdlib.h>` makes these available also in the global namespace, much as in the C Standard. —end example]

If you include the 'old-style' `XXX.h` header, it's placed in both namespaces (in *both* iterations of the standard).

Comment: The question is tagged c++ not c++0x

Comment: @Jay: Soon enough, there won't be much difference.

Comment: @Jay - Here C++0x merely documents how nearly all C++ compilers already work. In practice there is no difference.

Comment: So the compiler switches don't do anything? http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C-Dialect-Options.html and I guess the different levels of implementations of a changing standard don't require any thought either?

Comment: @DeadMG: So I guess all that legacy code is just going to vanish and nobody will ever have to maintain it?

Comment: @DeadMG @Jay Some of us are still maintaining code that can't use hardly any of the C++03 standard library, never mind *anything* from the newer revision.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using C++ you can rely on the function overloading.

There are three version of cos:

```
double cos (      double x );
float cos (       float x );
long double cos ( long double x );
```

But if you are using only C or you want portabilty only the double version of this function exists with this name. The float function is cosf.