# VS12 cmath polluting global namespace

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

Is it me or does it seem that `cmath` in VS12 is polluting the global namespace, by in every case including `math.h`? This way once it is included, symbols like `isfinite` are in the global namespace (whereas I would expect it only to be usable via `std::isfinite`).
Am I missing something or is there a way to force the correct behavior in VS12?

Comment: What do you think is the correct behaviour? AFAIK, `cmath` is allowed to `#include math.h`...

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11085916/why-are-some-functions-in-cmath-not-in-the-std-namespace

Comment: Also related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6215467/cmath-header-confusion. Note that this is not a Visual Studio specific problem, clang (libc++) and gcc (libstdc++) headers do the using-pull-up, too.

Comment: @Walter The expected behavior is to not put public API symbols into global namespace, since then I could also use `math.h` directly. They may include `math.h` but then it would need some magic to wrap symbols in `std`.

Comment: @abergmeier Read [Mike Seymour's](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11086087/2899559) quote of the standard: "It is unspecified whether these names are first declared within the global namespace scope..."

Comment: @AviGinsburg I stand corrected. And this is soo annoying.