# C++ Declaring function in namespace with same name as function in global namespace

Tags: c++, scope, cmath, global-namespace

I have a question regarding function declaration scopes in C++. Suppose using `#include <cmath>` introduces a function symbol into the global namespace. According to my understanding, in principle, it should only introduce symbols into the `std` namespace, but in practice, from my own experience, some symbols appear in the global namespace. This answer seems to confirm this: [cmath header confusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6215467/cmath-header-confusion).

Now, what happens when I declare a function (with the same prototype as the function from the global namespace) inside a `namespace foo { }`? Suppose for example, that `sqrt()` from `<cmath>` ends up in the global namespace, and I have:

```cpp
#include <cmath>

namespace foo {

    template <class T>
    T sqrt( T x ) {
        // do something extra...
        return std::sqrt( x );
    }

}

// ...

void foo::bar() {
    double a = 4.0;
    double b = sqrt( a );
}
```

The template is resolved to the symbol `double sqrt( double x )`, which seems like it should clash with the one in the global namespace. It seems to work, but is this generally a bad practice?

More generally, does a function declared inside a namespace take precedence over a global function, when used from inside the same namespace? Does this violate the C++ standard in any way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two separate issues here.

Firstly, it is true that pulling in certain headers injects symbols both in the global namespace, and in the `std` namespace. This sausage-making has to do with C++'s legacy, and roots, in C; and to try to have a good chance of getting legacy C code compilable in C++ with as little pain as possible.

Secondly, is is true that...

> a function declared inside a namespace take precedence over a global
>   function, when used from inside the same namespace?

That is correct. And, no, this does not

> violate the C++ standard in any way?

In fact, the C++ standard explicitly specifies that this is how things should work. Resolving a reference from a namespace first searches the same namespace, as the first order of business. Then the parent namespace, in case of a nested namespace. Then, eventually, the global namespace.

Then, `using namespace` makes things complicated. Which is why [you should not do that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).

And then finally, to make things interesting, there's also [argument dependent lookup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8111677/what-is-argument-dependent-lookup-aka-adl-or-koenig-lookup) that turns all these rules on their heads by searching for a function not in the current namespace, the parent namespace, or a global namespace, but in the same namespace as the functions' arguments.

Nobody has ever accused C++ of being simple.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out argument dependent lookup! It's a mechanism that I did not know about before.