# Using #include <cmath>, why it always select the long version of abs instead of choose due to the input type?

Tags: c++, mingw, std

I've noticed this strange thing on an app I'm using (trying to recreate [here](https://godbolt.org/z/Tr6K4szEr), not sure if I'm able).

Basically, if I include `#include <cmath>` and I call `abs()` function (without namespace), whatever values I pass to it (double, float, and so on) it seems to evaluate the int version of it:

[image]

If instead I specify std::abs(), it correctly takes the right method (double in this case):

[image]

Why this? Isn't `abs()` the same of `std::abs()` including `#include <cmath>`? Which function does it using "bypassing double" and always selecting the int version?

Comment: Please note that what you show is only the editors deduction, not the actual compiler when you build. Does it build without warnings? Does it produce the correct result?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude yes intellisense seems to be correct. If compiling, no warnings, and I get two different results. it seems that also on godbolt the two functions looks differents...

Comment: Also if you look closer at the first message, this overload seems to come from the `<stdlib.h>` header file.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude stdlib.h should be cstdlib, right? Which include ONLY the long version. But as I said, I explicitly include the cmath, which should "override" and extend it... isn't?

Comment: @Nickistired nope, because I'm including cmath library, as said in the post.

Comment: It's not required for `cmath` to place functions in the global namespace, in your case, it likely doesn't. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6215567/): *"using `<cmath>` gives you the symbols defined in the std namespace and **perhaps** also in the global namespace."* (emph. mine) (also see the references to the standard in [paxdiablo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6215534/3270037))

Comment: It's possible that `<cstdlib>` *is* included (indirectly, by some other header file), and it's a wrapper that includes `<stdlib.h>`. It's an implementation detail.

Comment: Somewhat related:  [Why is “using namespace std;” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting that result because it's allowed by the Standard. If you want `::abs`, include `<stdlib.h>`. If you want `std::abs`, include `<cmath>`.

In Standard C++, including one standard header may cause other headers to be included, but implementations vary in their choices (even between releases of the same implementation). And including `<cmath>` may put the C++ overloads in the global namespace. Again, implementations differ. For portable code, stick to what the standard says.